# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [Offices.getAllOffices]

Tags: jpa, illegalargumentexception, named-query

I'm getting started with JavaEE and Wildfly(JBoss Server App.). My project is already operational, but, when I try to start my .xhtml page I receive an error from the server app.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [Offices.getAllOffices]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty straight forward.  I'll copy the clear part out separate to reflect it

```
No query defined for that name [Offices.getAllOffices]
```

You're likely using a named query in your code, referring to this name.  This named query doesn't exist.